# How to create splashscreen in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi-xe2, splash-screen, firemonkey

I need to create a splashscreen while my FMX program is launching.

The following code from VCL does not works anymore:

```
SplashScreen := TSplashScreen.Create(Application);
SplashScreen.Show;
Application.Initialize;
SplashScreen.Update; //No such function in FMX
Application.Run;
```

Problem is that in FMX forms are not created/repainted until `Application.Run` executed, as they use some FMX magic to repaint. Using VCL splashscreen is not an option since I need OSX support.

How do I create a splashscreen in Delphi XE2 FireMonkey project?

Comment: @RRUZ: I don't see how general "delphi" tag is applied to the question, as it is specific to XE2 and FireMonkey.

Comment: Rodrigo thinks that every question related to Delphi should have the general `delphi` tag so that more people see it. :) I've removed it before when the question was extremely specific, and he's put it back in. I finally quit disagreeing with him. ;)

Comment: @Krom, @KenWhite explains why I tagged your question as `delphi`. Also the `firemonkey` tag  had only 49 followers and the tag `delphi-xe2` 80, but the `delphi` tag  has 1839, so if you uses the `delphi` tag you have more chances to get an answer to from a delphi developer.

Comment: @RRUZ: I see your point. But in the end that would mislead those Delphi developers who are not familiar with FMX or XE2, as those 2 are quite groundbreaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works - the difference being that the `Application` isn't made the `Owner` of the splash window, and that `Application.Initialize` is called before the splash window is created and displayed, but the main form isn't created until after the splash window is showing.

```
program Project2;

uses
  FMX.Forms,
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {MainForm},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {SplashForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  SplashForm := TSplashForm.Create(nil);
  SplashForm.Show;
  Sleep(1000);   // Whatever to control display time of splash screen

  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  SplashForm.Close;
  SplashForm.Free;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Just in case, cross-platform `Sleep` is implemented in SysUtils.

Comment: @Krom: Thanks! I couldn't remember (and didn't spend a lot of time looking). I used XE2 Update 3 when I tested the answer I posted, so I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: Weird. On a clean project it works fine. Answer accepted and I'm going to debug overnight .. Thank you!

Comment: Adding `Application.ProcessMessages;` after the `SplashForm.Show;` line solved the problem. @Ken: Perhaps you would want to include that into your answer.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry; I can't do that. :) I've never, ever used or advised use of PM, and can't do so now. There's got to be a better solution - I'll look later today when I get a chance, although it's hard to see what you might be able to do differently - you did say it worked fine without it in a clean project, so it must be something your specific app is doing, and of course I don't have that to test against.

Comment: @KenWhite To have the content of the SplashForm visible, add SplashForm.PaintTo(SplashForm.Canvas); after SplashForm.Show; instead of A.PM

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a separate TLayout and populate it as you desire. To do so;

- The splash layout must have the form as its direct owner.
- The rest of the form should be behind it. And the Form transparency should be enabled.
- In the FormCreate Event you can add code to do the necessary hiding of the other form controls which can be made easy if you add them to a separate single or set of layouts and hide them instead.
- You will also require a kind of triggering event for hiding the splash layout and showing the rest of the form as you may desire.

**Note:** This approach though doesn't show the standard form buttons on the splash screen.

I have done this many a times and it proves to be quiet less complicated than making a separate form and handling it alongside the main form.