# Delphi XE7 Firemonkey Splash screen Form Show

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-xe2, show, firemonkey

I'm trying to create a splash screen in a delphi xe7 firemonkey application, but firemonkey does not recognise form.update.

I had do it with Delphi Xe7 Vcl with the following code, and is working perfeclty:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IniFiles, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Buttons, Shellapi;

type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    procedure FormCreate( Sender: TObject );

  end;

var
  Form1   : TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate( Sender: TObject );
begin
          Sleep( 1000 );
          Form2.Close;
          Form2.Release;
end;
end.
```

Second Form:

```
unit Unit2;
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IniFiles, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  Image1: TImage;
 private
 public
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}


initialization


        Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
        Form2.Show;
        Form2.Update;

end.
```

But with Firemonkey, it doesn't work. Form2.Update is not recognise Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate, [How to create splashscreen in FireMonkey?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9079347/576719).

Comment: I tried such way, but is not working. Thanks

Comment: Sleeping in the main thread is not a good idea. Use a timer instead.

Comment: it was answer but not completly in the same answer. I make it work with  :begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  Form2.Show;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sleep(1000);   // Whatever to control display time of splash screen

  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Form2.Close;
  Form2.Free;
  Application.Run;

end.

Comment: `Application.ProcessMessages` and `Sleep()` are never a solution. Read this, [A Splash Screen for Delphi on Android](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/splash_screen_delphi_android.html).

Comment: @Ken and LU, Gentlemen, with due respect for your experience and knowledge I must say that you linked to a SO question for which both answers are problematic. Tested in XE6 with FMX desktop on Win7 the first answer does not show the content (I used a TLabel and a TImage) of the SplashForm. The second answer is not really a splash form solution. The motivation for a splash form is often that the creation and initialization of the main form takes a long time and we want to show the user that the application is starting. Adding a layout to the main form doesn't help.

Comment: @Ken and LU, In the linked-to SO question, the first answer can be made working by adding Application.ProcessMessages right after SplashForm.Show. You both say A.PM is a no-no and I agree with that in general, but I think an exception to the rule is required here.

Comment: @LURD Marco did not show the code how he is creating the Splash/Menu form, but assuming he does it in the standard Appplication.CreateForm() way, that form becomes the main form, which is OK in his scenario. However, a splash form is usually (in a desktop application at least) something you want to get rid of when the application is up and running.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I agree that not all answers to questions here at SO are perfect or even correct. One possibility is to offer a bounty and make clear what is missing, or link to that question and explain.

Comment: Replace Form2.Update; with Form2.PaintTo(Form2.Canvas);