# Create own Splashscreen Delphi 10 seattle

Tags: delphi, mobile, firemonkey, splash-screen, delphi-10-seattle

Instead of using the png images through the project options for a splashscreen I want to use my own Form for a splashscreen.

I've found a solution for XE2 in the following link, but it doesn't work for Delphi 10 Seattle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080804/2728408

Below I have some examples I've tried in my project .dpr:

**Example 1:**

```
program Project2;

uses
  FMX.Forms,
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {MainForm},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {SplashForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  SplashForm := TSplashForm.Create(nil);
  SplashForm.Show;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sleep(1000);   // Whatever to control display time of splash screen

  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  SplashForm.Close;
  SplashForm.Free;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Example 2:**

```
program Project2;

uses
  FMX.Forms,
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {MainForm},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {SplashForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TSplashForm, SplashForm);
  Application.Run;
  Sleep(1000);
  Application.Terminate;// Also tried Application.Destroy
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Example 3:**

```
program Project2;

uses
  FMX.Forms,
  System.SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {MainForm},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {SplashForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TSplashForm, SplashForm);
  Application.Run;
  Sleep(1000);
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  SplashForm.Close;
  Application.ProcessMessages;     
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Anyone has a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should not interfere with Application.Terminare/Inititalse the way you do it in the code.

In Firemonkey, you can change the main form of the application in runtime. So, you should show your splash form first, do all the job you want and then switch to your main form.

See this for an example: http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2016/01/22/a-splash-form-in-firemonkey/

```
procedure TFormSplash.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartupTimer.Enabled := false;
  StartupTimer.Interval := 500; // can be changed to improve startup speed in later releases
end;

procedure TFormSplash.SplashImagePaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
begin
  StartupTimer.Enabled := not FInitialized;
end;

procedure TFormSplash.StartupTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartupTimer.Enabled := false;
  if not FInitialized then begin
    FInitialized := true;
    LoadMainForm;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormSplash.LoadMainForm;
var
  form: TForm;
begin
  form := TMainForm.Create(Application);
  form.Show;
  Application.MainForm := form;
  Close;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have been doing for the past 3 days or so.

First: Create the form of the splash screen. Like normal loading of Delphi/C++ IDE, it has an indicator that "xxxx dll is loading..". So the basic steps are to include the splash screen as part of the usual loading of the main application.

Second: Remember that your DPR file takes a vital role in loading and/or creating all the forms. Although I agree with the VCL function (Application.ProcessMessages) to show to the user that it is creating the form.

Third: Never run a procedure in your Main Form OnCreate Event except for Skinning or to instantiate the skin. But call it again in the DPR once the Main Form is created.

Fourth: Disable first your Main Form once it is created, so that the user will not click on buttons or whatever then re-enable it when the Splash Screen is hidden.

Here is the DPR:

```
program xxxx;

uses
  Forms, MidasLib,.....

{$R *.res}

begin
   Application.Initialize;
   Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
   Application.Title := 'xxxxx';
   SplashFrm := TSplashFrm.Create(Application);
  try
   Application.CreateForm(TMain_Form, Main_Form);
   Main_Form.Skinning;
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   SplashFrm.FormStyle := TFormStyle.fsStayOnTop;
   Main_Form.Enabled := False;
   Main_Form.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMaximized;
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   SplashFrm.Show; //Never use showModal coz splash form needs to be closed first and create all the rest of the forms.
   SplashFrm.Label5.Caption := 'Loading... Database handlers..';
   Application.CreateForm(TDM, DM);
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   SplashFrm.Label5.Caption := 'Loading... Login Libraries..';
   Application.CreateForm(TLogin_Frm, Login_Frm);
   Application.ProcessMessages;

   .....// All the rest of the Forms.
   Main_Form.DSiTrimWorkingSet; //[StockOverflow/questions/2031577][1] 

  finally
   SplashFrm.Free;
   Main_Form.Check_Registration;
   Main_Form.Checking_Internet_Proc;
   Main_Form.Enabled := True;
   Main_Form.sStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Ready...';
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   Main_Form.DSiTrimWorkingSet;
  end;
 Application.Run;
end.
```